# Dispose not working

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe, dispose

I'm re-programming one of my old login screen codes and I am changing the:

```
JPasswordField.getText();
```

To:

```
JPasswordFieald.getPassword();
```

Which is a lot harder because it outputs charecters.

Anyway, JFrame.dispose() isnt working for me. I want my program to dispose an old JFrame to a new JFrame (e.e JFrame2).

Here is my code:

```
public class Launcher {

    //Define Variables
    public static String VER = "1.1.0";
    public static String STATE = " ALPHA ";
    public static JFrame launcher;
    public static char[] sPass;
    public static String sUser;

    //Create widgets
    public static JTextField User = new JTextField();
    public static JPasswordField Pass = new JPasswordField();
    public static JButton Login = new JButton("Login");

    //Runs when program starts
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewFrame("Infinite Doom Launcher");

        //Checks if login has been pressed
        Login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                 sUser = User.getText();
                 sPass = Pass.getPassword();

                 //checks if password is correct
                 if(CheckPass(sPass)) {
                     if(sUser.equals("genfy")){
                        Game.main(null);
                        launcher.dispose();
                     }
                 }
             }
        });

    }

    //Creates new frame
    public static void NewFrame(String Name) {
        JFrame launcher = new JFrame(Name + " " + STATE + VER);
        launcher.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        launcher.setSize(500,95);
        launcher.setResizable(false);

        //Add widgets to a Border Layout
        launcher.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        launcher.add(User, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        launcher.add(Pass, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        launcher.add(Login, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Set visible
        launcher.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Checks if the entered password is correct
    private static boolean CheckPass(char[] input) {
        boolean isCorrect = true;
        char[] correctPassword = { 'g', 'e', 'n', 'f', 'y', 'g', 'e', 'n', 'y', 's' };

        if (input.length != correctPassword.length) {
            isCorrect = false;
        } else {
            isCorrect = Arrays.equals (input, correctPassword);
        }

        //Zero out the password.
        Arrays.fill(correctPassword,'0');

        return isCorrect;
    }
}
```

So the problem seems to be occurring at:

```
             //checks if password is correct
             if(CheckPass(sPass)) {
                 if(sUser.equals("genfy")){
                    Game.main(null);
                    launcher.dispose();
                 }
```

specifically:

```
launcher.dispose();
```

So when I press JButton(login) this error appears:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at main.Launcher$1.actionPerformed(Launcher.java:42)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I apologize for my code being so long.

Comment: You can try extending your entire class to `JFrame` and then call `this.dispose()`, which in my opinion would work better. Also you have only declared the `launcher` but have not used it anywhere, so that's why you're getting the error. You must assign the `launcher` to your class in order for you to dispose it. Currently, your `Launcher` class does not have a user interface like `JFrame` assigned to it at all, so there's no way to dispose it.

Comment: unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: related: check line 42 for objects that might be null - and fix them :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a scope problem in `NewFrame` method at this line:

```
JFrame launcher = new JFrame(Name + " " + STATE + VER);
```

This `launcher` variable is local to `NewFrame` method and is hidding `launcher` class member. So when you call `launcher.dispose()` within `actionPerformed()` method you get a `NullPointerException`. To solve this you should do this change:

```
launcher = new JFrame(Name + " " + STATE + VER);
```

And also take a look to this topic: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

#### Off-topic

As @kleopatra has suggested, learn about java naming conventions and stick to them. See more in this document: [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)